# QtCreator shortcut for enable/disable breakpoint

Tags: qt-creator

One of the useful shortcut during debugging software via debugger is the shortcut to Enable/Disable Breakpoint.

I checked [Qt Creator documentaion](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html), but I didn't find such thing.

I have found only delete/append breakpoint via **F9**

Does it exist some workaround or How Disable/Enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you won't find it. I just check in Qt-creator source code for the feature and enabling/disabling break point command only exists through contextual menu in editor or breakpoint viewer. As the menu is dynamic and the associated action is just temporary in the code, no way to attach here a shortcut.

Maybe you could try with a feature request at Qt Creator bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, in Qt Creator 11.0.1, this is possible. It's default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

To change it, in main menu go to *Edit* > *Preferences*. In the vertical tab choose *Environment*. Then go to *Keyboard* tab. Search for "breakpoint".

There is a command `EnableOrDisableBreakpoint` with Label *Enable or Disable Breakpoint*.